# Installing Hadoop, ZooKeeper, AccumuLo on Mac

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, accumulo

I am attempting to install these technologies on a OS X loaded with Mountain Lion for testing purposes.  The setup is a single-node setup using 'localhost'.

I am running into a few issues...

1) running sudo zkCli -> ls / throws an error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1468)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1496)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processZKCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:725)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:593)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.executeLine(ZooKeeperMain.java:365)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.run(ZooKeeperMain.java:323)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.main(ZooKeeperMain.java:282)
```

2) I attempt to run bin/accumulo init and receive this error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/accumulo/start/Platform
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.accumulo.start.Platform
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/accumulo/start/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.accumulo.start.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

It seems that there is something wrong with my class but I am not sure what I need to do.

Here is the summary of the AccumuLo compile:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Project ........................... SUCCESS [17.267s]
[INFO] Trace ............................................. SUCCESS [7.819s]
[INFO] Fate .............................................. SUCCESS [2.638s]
[INFO] Start ............................................. SUCCESS [49.560s]
[INFO] Core .............................................. SUCCESS [2:57.195s]
[INFO] Server ............................................ SUCCESS [23.385s]
[INFO] Examples .......................................... SUCCESS [0.321s]
[INFO] Simple Examples ................................... SUCCESS [19.038s]
[INFO] MiniCluster ....................................... SUCCESS [38.770s]
[INFO] Accumulo Maven Plugin ............................. SUCCESS [20.568s]
[INFO] Testing ........................................... SUCCESS [2:55.802s]
[INFO] Proxy ............................................. SUCCESS [1:36.702s]
[INFO] Assemblies ........................................ SUCCESS [17.033s]
[INFO] Documentation ..................................... SUCCESS [0.282s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10:49.977s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 29 15:05:17 EDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/83M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Is Zookeeper running?

2) I would recommend running Accumulo from the binary tarball download instead of building it yourself.  If you must build it, use mvn package -P assemble.  Are you running from trunk?  If so, we no longer run accumulo from the source directory.  Look for a built tarball in assemble/target, install that and run it.  Is accumulo-env.sh configured properly?  Do you have any old environment variables configured in your bash scripts setting an incorrect ACCUMULO_HOME?